# В Swift 4.2+ поменять местами символы в строке, находящиеся на определенных позициях

Tags: строки, swift4

см. комментарий в коде:

```
import Foundation

let someString = "1234567"

func reverse(_ str: String) -> String {
    var str = str

    var indexLeft = 0
    var indexRight = str.count - 1

    while indexLeft < indexRight {
        let a = str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: indexLeft)]
        let b = str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: indexRight)]

        // ???: какой самый простой, лаконичный и правильный способ поменять символы a и b,
        // находящиеся на позициях indexLeft и indexRight, местами в строке

        //
        // FIXME: я сделал вот так, но, уверен, есть способ элегантнее
        //

        str = String(str.prefix(indexLeft) + String(b) + str.suffix(from: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: indexLeft + 1)))
        str = String(str.prefix(indexRight) + String(a) + str.suffix(from: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: indexRight + 1)))

        //
        //
        //

        indexLeft += 1
        indexRight -= 1
    }

    return str
}

print(reverse(someString)) // 7654321
```

UPDATE: нет, встроенный метод .reversed() у String мне не подойдет (почему не подойдет? - потому что это задачка с Leetcode). Вопрос не в том, чтобы сделать реверс. Вопрос касается именно оптимизации строковых операций - как-то они сейчас и выглядят слишком громоздко и выполняются слишком долго (иногда тесткейс, содержащий ооочень длинную строку, например, завершается time limit exceeded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не выходить за рамки операций со строками, то имхо единственное что тут можно сделать это заменить suffix(from:) на suffix(), таким образом получится избавиться от двух вызовов index(:offsetBy:). Больше ничего в голову не приходит ...

```
let strLastIndex = str.count - 1 // запомнить до цикла while

str = String(str.prefix(indexLeft) + String(b) + str.suffix(strLastIndex - indexLeft))
str = String(str.prefix(indexRight) + String(a) + str.suffix(strLastIndex - indexRight))
```

Answer (score 2):

а встроенная не пойдет ?

```
var someString = "1234567"
someString = String(someString.reversed())
print(someString)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. не подойдет - дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Самое короткое решение.

```
func reverse(_ s: String) -> String {
    return String(s.characters.reversed())
}
```

Comment: тогда уж return String(s.reversed()) - будет еще короче; но вы, похоже, недочитали вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Самое лаконичное решение:

```
extension String {
    mutating func swapAt(_ index1: Int, _ index2: Int) {
        var characters = Array(self)
        characters.swapAt(index1, index2)
        self = String(characters)
    }
}
```

И использование:

```
str.swapAt(indexLeft, indexRight)
```

Возможно вы не хотите создавать extension, тогда так:

```
var characters = Array(str)
characters.swapAt(indexLeft, indexRight)
str = String(characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если чисто по алгоритму, то наверно так:

```
import UIKit

var someString = "1234567"

var arrray = Array(someString)

for i in 0...someString.count/2 {
    let temp = arrray[i]
    arrray[i] = arrray[someString.count - i-1]
    arrray[someString.count - i-1] = temp
}
someString = String(arrray)
print(someString)
```

Comment: у массивов есть метод swap() и можно не использовать временную переменную ) но задачка про строки, а не про массивы

Answer (score 1):

Решение без reverse:

```
func reverse(_ str: String) -> String {
    var strArray = Array(str.characters)
    var i = 0
    while(i < strArray.count/2)
    {
        let tmp = strArray[i];
        strArray[i] = strArray[strArray.count - 1 - i]
        strArray[strArray.count - 1 - i] = tmp
        i += 1
    }
    return String(strArray)
}
```